# Common phone/tablet media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm not jQuery Expert , However I have a site with a video header , and the problem is that I need to remove the div containing the video tag if viewed from a smartphone/tablet.

How can I do that? I'm sure it's something super-straightforward

Comment: Have a look at [JQuery.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@media` CSS rules will help

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px){
     #div_to_hide{display:none;}
  }
```

Further reading: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)